# Program Just Repeats Prompt and then Ends no Matter what I Input (using Lua 5.1)

Tags: lua, lua-5.1

I am working with Lua 5.1. This is the program I am currently trying to run.

```
print ("What is your name?")
playerName = io.read()

print ("Are you a boy or a girl?")
playerGender = io.read()
repeat
    if playerGender ~= "boy" or "girl" or "male" or "female" then
        print ("I'm sorry, that is not a valid answer.")
        print ("Are you a boy or a girl?")
        playerGender = io.read()
    end
until (playerGender == "boy" or "girl" or "male" or "female")
```

No matter what, whether I enter one of the valid answers or if it's just random gibberish- the program responds with "I'm sorry, that is not a valid answer. Are you a boy or a girl?" Then you are prompted to enter your gender again- but no matter what the answer it just terminates the program- or it carries on to whatever other code there is to run.

Is there anything wrong with my code or logic that would be making the program to behave this way? Should I use something else other than the "repeat - if - then - end - else" block I am currently using? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is a misconception about how comparison and boolean operators work. The following line will always evaluate to `true`:

```
playerGender ~= "boy" or "girl" or "male" or "female"
```

Why is that? To make clearer what happens, let's add some parenthesis to show how the expression is evaluted according to [operator precedence](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.6):

```
(playerGender ~= "boy") or ("girl") or ("male") or ("female")
```

This means, we have four expressions connected with `or` operators. This means, if any of those sub-expressions is truthy, the whole expression is true. In Lua, [all values except for `false` and `nil`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.2) are truthy. As all three strings `"girl"`, `"male"` and `"female"` are truthy, the entire expression is always true.

The following will do what you want:

```
(playerGender ~= "boy") and (playerGender ~= "girl") and (playerGender ~= "male") and (playerGender ~= "female")
```

Now you have four expressions connected with `and` operators, which means, all of the sub-expressions need to be true (i.e. all string comparisons are unequal) for the entire expression to be true.

The `until` condition has the same problem, i.e. the expression is always truthy because the strings always are truthy. You could simplify the loop as follows:

```
while playerGender ~= "boy" and playerGender ~= "girl" and playerGender ~= "male" and playerGender ~= "female" do
    print ("I'm sorry, that is not a valid answer.")
    print ("Are you a boy or a girl?")
    playerGender = io.read()
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is such a help to understanding the logic of Lua and coding in general. This makes so much more sense now! I really appreciate your help! This definitely goes to show how sensitive and specific programming languages want you to be when writing your code at times. Again, thank you so much! I will definitely keep this in mind when later writing programs with these sorts of conditions!

Comment: Glad it helped! (If this solves your problem, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.)